# Why SortedDictionary.GetEnumerator() is an O(log n) operation in C# according to Microsoft Docs?

Tags: c#, time-complexity, sortedset, sorteddictionary

According to [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1), the `SortedDictionary.GetEnumerator()` method is an O(log n) operation in C#. `SortedDictionary` is backed by `SortedSet`. Looking at [.NET source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs,e3950ee0470d0408) line 1911 to 1923, when the `GetEnumerator()` method is called, a new Enumerator is instantiated which creates a `Stack<T>` internally. Then the `Stack<T>` is filled in in the Initialize() method. This is an O(n) operation, not O(log n)!

I'd appreciate it if someone explains the reason for O(log n).

Comment: The internal representation is a binary tree, and apparently the stack structure allocated by the enumerator has room for two entries for each level in the tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the Stack is filled in in the Initialize() method. This is an O(n) operation, not O(log n)!

No, not really. The `Stack<T>` collection is filled only to the deepest level of the binary tree representing the sorted data. The `Initialize()` method traverses the binary tree, pushing data nodes onto the stack until it reaches the first node that will be returned by the enumerator.

The binary tree's depth is log n, and the `Initialize()` method loops just once per level of the tree, so the cost of the loop is also O(log n). Just like the documentation says.

The *overall* cost of enumerating the collection will be O(n), but simply initializing the enumerator is only O(log n).